# OPC Client hangs in case of loss of connection

Tags: c#, winforms, opc

When the form is loaded, a timer starts in the GetItemsnaliv() method, which connects to the remote OPC server and retrieves the required data.
Code:

```
bool GetItemsNaliv()
{
  IsWork2 = true;
  try {
    if (_opcServer2 != null && !_opcServer2.IsConnected) {
      _opcServer2.Connect(url2, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    IsWork2 = false;
    return false;
  }
```

If the OPC-server is disconnected or suddenly for some reason reboots, the program just freezes and can be killed only through the Manager. The error occurs in this line:

```
_opcServer2.Connect(url2, new Opc.ConnectData(new System.Net.NetworkCredential()));
```

How to avoid program hang-up if connection is lost and start reconnection?

Answer (score 0):

Before claiming that the program froze completely, give it a time. Wait for 6 minutes, there is a DCOM timeout that is that long. Most likely you will get an exception after that time.  ( http://www.opclabs.com/resources/technology-opc/opc-q-a/1075-what-is-the-6-minute-dcom-timeout )

The only solution to this, for better responsiveness, is then to run the activity on a separate thread, and implement your own, much shorter, timeout logic around that. Or, use an OPC library/toolkit.component that already has this logic built in.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
Program still froze after 10 min waiting.
The exception that I got:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException" in OpcNetApi.dll

Comment: Can you please be clearer. Do you get an exception, or does the program freeze? I think you cannot have both at the same time. And. if there is an exception, what it the message text?